# Invalid token 'event' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

i got post response from slack with event property so i want to create model for event with below code

```
public Event event { get; set; } //getting error here


public class Event
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
            public string user { get; set; }
            public string text { get; set; }
            public string ts { get; set; }
            public string channel { get; set; }
            public string event_ts { get; set; }
        }
'''

got error in declaring event as name
```

Comment: `event` is a keyword. You can name the property `Event` (having the same name as a type is legal) but it's probably better to name `Event` something more specific so no clash with generic C# concepts is possible (`ChannelEvent` or the like).

Comment: `event` is a keyword, prefix it with `@` (`Event @event`), or rename it

Comment: David's answer explains one option - but I'd suggest renaming all your properties to follow .NET naming conventions, which will avoid the issue in the first place. You should be able to use attributes to specify how your C# properties map to JSON property names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `event` is a reserved keyword in C#, you'd need to tell the compiler that this is specifically *not* using that keyword.  You can use `@` for that:

```
public Event @event { get; set; }
```

(As an aside: This is most commonly seen in View code where we need an anonymous object to have a `class` property for CSS rules.)

---

*If possible* however, it's recommended that you maintain C# naming conventions and translate between those conventions in your JSON serialization/deserialization.  Depending on how you perform that task there are different ways to approach it, such as using property attributes or a custom serializer.

Using `Event` as a class name might not be ideal either.  Try to be descriptive to avoid conflicting with anything common in the language.  Your udpated code might look something like:

```
public ChatEvent Event { get; set; }

//...
public class ChatEvent
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Ts { get; set; }
    public string Channel { get; set; }
    public string Event_ts { get; set; }
}
```